# How to get the inner html of an element using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

This is my HTML document

```
<div class='my-class'>
    <p>some text</p>
</div>
```

I want to get the inner HTML of `div.my-class` element, which is:

```
<p>some text</p>
```

The inner html is not always a `<p>` it could be some other element.

Here is what I have tried but not able to get the desired output:

```
res = response.css('div.my-class').get(); 

/* result */
<div class='my-class'>
 <p>some text</p>
</div>

//-------------------------------------------

res = response.css('div.my-class::text').get(); 

/* result */
some text
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to get the children of the element of class my-class:

```
html = "<div class='my-class'><p>some text</p></div>"
response = Selector(text=html, type="html")
print(response.xpath('//*[@class="my-class"]/*').get())
```

Answer (score 0):

The following CSS selector gets the expected output (* matches all descendant elements):

```
res = response.css('div.my-class::text *').get(); 

/* result */
<p>some text</p>
```

---

Note that if you have **multiple child elements**, then you need to use `getall()` to get the entire inner html, for example, if you have the following input:

```
<div class='my-class'>
    <h1>heade</h1>
    <p>
        outter paragraph
        <p>
            inner paragraph
            <link>label</label>
        </p>
    </p>
    
</div>
```

Then you can get all the inner elements, and join them into a single string variable:

```
// get all immediate children and put them into an array
res_array = response.css('div.my-class::text > *').getall(); 

// join the array elements into res
res = " ".join(res_array);
```

*Note: if you don't include > before *, then it would recursively go through the inner elements, which means the inner elements appear more than one in the array*

Comment: `response.css('div.my-class::text > *').getall();` gives me an error `SelectorSyntaxError: Got pseudo-element ::text not at the end of a selector`